# Why did my Craftbukkit 1.7.2 map reset?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I am running a small homeserver with the latest craftbukkit 1.7.2 build.

Whenever they release a new version, I update my server asap.

However the last update somehow "reset" the map.
Spawnposition is now somehwere under ground, our buildings have all disappeared and the whole map looks like a fully new generated map.

I am wondering if this has something to do with the update or if the cause is more likely to be a plugin I have installed.

Following plugins are installed (they all are at latest version):

- AntiCreeper3
- CommandBin
- DeathControl
- PermissionBukkit

This is not a big issue to us as we hadn't built a lot. However I would like to know what causes this because we wan't to start a "permanent" LAN-server.

Comment: I hope this doesn't happen to you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

The problem was, that when you have no static level-seed specified in the properties-file, it will regenerate the map with a different seed every time the server restarts.

I could fix it by defining a static level-seed value.

Comment: I hope that's a bug and not a feature!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the properties file was overwritten with the update, and is likely loading a world that is, in fact, new.

This is probably due to you naming your world something other than "world" so, the folder it looks for when it loads the server will be whatever is set in the properties for the server, which is set by default to "world".

Just open the .properties file and set the default world to the folder name(your world name) from before and it will load that world.

As for the issue being plugin related, generally it wouldn't destroy your items, and if the plugins had issues, you would see it while breaking blocks, or the server simply wouldn't load the world at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that out tomorrow evening (don't have time before then)

Comment: I took a look at my server.properties. The level-name is still the same...